# google app scripts Find Value then copy entire row

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm really new to google sheets app script. I need an script which finds a date in row 1, selects the entire row and copy and paste values only. This is because I have formulas in each column which will only work if row 1 matches =today().

Answer (score 0):

To get the range values and save into a variable (copy):

```
var book = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url); //url=spread sheet url
var sheet = book.getSheetByName("sheet name");
var range = sheet.getRange(a, b, x, y).getValues(); 
//a=inicial row ,b=inicial column, x=last row, y=last column
// range will be a bidimensional array
// "A1" cell value will be: range[0][0]
```

To append in new cells (paste): //you have to iterate the array

```
sheet.appendRow([range]);
```